# how to convert this date string to "2011-02-15T12:00+00:00" python datetime object

Tags: python

how to convert this date string to "2011-02-15T12:00+00:00" python datetime object in following format "Wed, Feb, 15, 2011 15:00" ?

Answer (score 7):

It seems ISO 8601 format. Try using [iso8601](http://code.google.com/p/pyiso8601/) package — you can install it through `pip` or `easy_install`.

> Many file formats and standards use the ISO 8601 date format (e.g. 2007-01-14T20:34:22+00:00) to store dates in a neutral, unambiguous manner. This simple module parses the most common forms encountered and returns datetime objects.
>
> ```
> >>> import iso8601
> >>> iso8601.parse_date("2007-06-20T12:34:40+03:00")
> datetime.datetime(2007, 6, 20, 12, 34, 40, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '+03:00'>)
> >>> iso8601.parse_date("2007-06-20T12:34:40Z")
> datetime.datetime(2007, 6, 20, 12, 34, 40, tzinfo=<iso8601.iso8601.Utc object at 0x100ebf0>)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you know the exact format of the date string, you can parse it to extract each value.

I'm not sure what the +00:00 part means, so I'll ignore that for now.

```
str="2011-02-15T12:00+00:00"
year=int(str[:4])
month=int(str[5:7])
day=int(str[8:10])
hour=int(str[11:13])
minute=int(str[14:16])
date = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)
```

Comment: The last +00:00 part means its time zone is UTC.